# Regex match string until unwanted part

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have a string like this;

`[0]: http//www.somelink.com[Some Text][0]`

`[Some Text][0]` is optional. It can be there or not.

I want to match `[0]: http//www.somelink.com` with 0 is changed to 1

To do this I used this code; `string.replace(/(\[)\d+(\]:.+)(\[.*?\]\[\d+\])?/, "$11$2");`

But i guess becouse `(\[.*?\]\[\d+\])?` is optional `+` consumes all the characters even if there is [Some Text][0] or not

I also tried `string.replace(/(\[)\d+(\]:[^\\[]+)(\[.*?\]\[\d+\])?/, "$11$2");` this worked but if there is a [ before [Some Text][0] `+` stop matching

and I also tried this `string.replace(/(\[)\d+(\]:.+)(?!\[.*?\]\[\d+\])/, "$11$2");` but again + consumes everything

Is there any way to match every character including `[`, until `[Some Text][0]?`

Comment: Change all `\[\d+\]` to `[1]` if string matches `somelink.com` ? What about [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6mn1387/)

Comment: From your regex it looks like you are trying to change [0] http to '[1] http' and delete the '[Some Text][0]' Why is this ambiguous? Also, is this an example of an entire string?

Comment: @Jonny 5 i used `d` becouse it can be any number

Comment: @sln i try to make Stackoverflow's add link button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   \[\d+\]:\s*http.*?(?=(\[.*?\]\[\d+\])|$)
```

This matches both.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9iD2/5

Comment: `(\[)\d+(\]:\s*http.*?)(?=(\[.*?\]\[\d+\])|$)` with the capture groups for the OP replacement question.